# How to determine the status of snapping in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3

I can use [toggleEnabled](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Snapping/QgsSnappingUtils.html#qgis.core.QgsSnappingUtils.toggleEnabled) to turn snapping on and off, but is there anyway to know the status of the snapping tool (on or off)? as toggleEnabled doesn't return a value nor does it take a value.

Comment: Python questions should include Python code. What have you tried? What error are you getting? Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: There are no errors. I don't know how to know the status of a tool

Comment: Does dump() have the info? https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Snapping/QgsSnappingUtils.html#qgis.core.QgsSnappingUtils.dump

Answer (score 2):

You can check enabled status in QgsSnappingConfig. Access this through the QgsSnappingUtils.config() method. For example, working within the QGIS Python window using iface:

```
enabled = iface.mapCanvas().snappingUtils().config().enabled()
```

This will return True or False